# Replacing string in file with perl

Tags: regex, perl, shell

I have a list of about 10 servers that I would like to change a string in all 10 servers.

I have written a script that looks at the file and with a loop and should use `perl -i -pe` to change the line `/opt/nimsoft/bin/niminit "" "start"` to `#/opt/nimsoft/bin/niminit "" "start"` (add a # to comment out)

```
oldstring = /opt/nimsoft/bin/niminit "" "start"

newstring = #/opt/nimsoft/bin/niminit "" "start"
```

I am having trouble escaping the /, I have tried \ and \Q and \E. Any ideas?

```
  for i in `cat $file`
  do

    echo "Disable application on startup"

     oldstring=start /opt/nimsoft/bin/niminit "" "start"
     newstring=#start /opt/nimsoft/bin/niminit "" "start"
    ssh -t $i sudo perl -p -i -e 's/oldstring/newstring/g' /etc/rc.tcpip
    #  /etc/rc.tcpip:start /opt/nimsoft/bin/niminit "" "start"
    echo "==============================================="
  done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `s{}{}` instead of `s///`, you won't have to worry about escaping the forward slashes.

The following adds a comment before the string that you wanted to match if it isn't already commented:

```
perl -i -pe 's{(?<!#)(?=start /opt/nimsoft/bin/niminit "" "start")}{#}' /etc/rc.tcpip
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl will permit the use of delimiters other than /. You might try ~ or { } pairs. Also, sed might be easier to use than a Perl script.